# qt websocket client handshake issue

Tags: qt, websocket, handshake

I am trying to connect the echo web socket server on Windows using Qt. I can connect to the web socket server using java or javascript, yet Qt does not work. It gets stuck at the handshake state. Below you can find the code snippet to connect to the web socket server:

```
qDebug() << "Trying to connect to the Echo Server";

connect(this, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(onConnected()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(onClosed()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), this, SLOT(onStateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(textFrameReceived(QString,bool)), this, SLOT(onTextFrameReceived(QString,bool)));

this->ignoreSslErrors();

this->open((QUrl("ws://echo.websocket.org")));
```

When this code is run, the console shows the following:

```
Trying to connect to the Echo Server
New socket status:  QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState
```

When inspected with Wireshark, we observe that both HTTP messages from client to the server and server to the client are sent and received. Afterwards, we do not see any upgrade to web socket protocol.

The callback functions stateChanged, error or textFrameReceived are never called and the status remains as Connecting, never gets to connected. I tried it using Qt 5.7 and 5.8. The compiler is MinGW 5.3.0. The operating system is Windows 10 64 bit.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: this `connect` suggest that you did inheritance of `QWebSocket`, this is wrong. Also you are connecting to echo server and you do not send anything.

Comment: I tried both encapsulation and inheritance. The result is the same.

Comment: I found something interesting. I have a class which calls this connector class. I moved calling the connector class to the main.cpp and called it directly. Then it connected to the web socket server. When I call the connector class from any other object, it cannot connect. The other class extends QObject. What might be the reason?

Comment: Have you check to open websocket with Qtimer (100ms delay for example), so don't call the open websocket on the constructor.